# Swap CSS background image on hover

Tags: css

I am currently using css to set the background image:

```
html {
font-size:100%;
margin-top: 0px;
background: url(http://vagrantpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Motorcycle-Wallpapers-HD-1-1-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

}
```

What I would like to do is use an other image on hover, how can I do this in CSS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the :hover pseudo element. But are you sure you want to do this in the entire html selector?

```
html:hover {
  background: url([NEW IMAGE URL]) no-repeat center center fixed;   
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I did think that using the html element like this might break the page but it appears to be fine, so thanks!

Comment: Welcome :-) Don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The :hover CSS [pseudo-class](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/#section_css-pseudo-class) matches when the user designates an element with a pointing device

`html:hover{
 background:  url(https://c7.staticflickr.com/9/8612/28620325150_e6892291ea_n.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}`

Comment: Could you expand on this answer to explain why this would work?